# What are the next three letters in the pattern "OTTFFSS"?

Tags: pattern, letters, letter-sequence

This is a very easy puzzle when the reasoning clicks:

> What are the next three letters in the pattern "OTTFFSS"?

So what are they?

HINT:

> This is the first hint

Answer (score 1):

Next letters are:

> ENT (it's even a word!)

How come?

> The letters are the initials of numbers in the English language (**O**ne, **T**wo, **T**hree...)

Comment: _How_ did you find out so fast? Was it that easy?

Comment: Couldn't even tell you myself, brains are wonderful and mysterious, mine's no exception.

Comment: @HexagonalImpossibilities I'm afraid this one is a classic and has been asked here before - see the duplicate I've linked above...

Comment: *sigh* no way half of the questions I ask get closed because of that- I promise I was _not_ copying that guy

Comment: @HexagonalImpossibilities It's fine :) I'd suggest doing a quick search of some of your keywords or terms in the 'Search on Puzzling...' box at the top of the page before posting one-liners or short riddles. The site's been open for several years now and a lot of 'quickies' of this style have already been posted in some form. In time you'll get a feel for what's likely already been done before. Chin up! :)

Comment: I _do_ that every time in that "similar questions" thingie below the title (scrolling down all the way)- I really do not know how you guys find duplicates so fast. Thanks for your advice anyway!